# Why is it necessary to specify paddingRight when paddingLeft is defined in android?

Tags: android, lint

I was working with the android lint. I came across one of the lint warnings **RtlSymmetry**. It states that

> If you specify padding or margin on the left side of a layout, you
>   should probably also specify padding on the right side (and vice
>   versa) for right-to-left layout symmetry.

I have searched over the internet but didn't get any reason for doing this. If we add paddingRight an unnecessary attribute is added. Can anyone please guide me through this? I wanted to know what is its impact over an application.

Comment: It probably just means that adding the same amount of padding to either side will make your view centered and therefore look nicer. You can ignore it if there's a reason why you're leaving paddingRight out.

Comment: @MatterCat Does it make any sense adding `paddingRight=0`

Comment: it is not "necessary", otherwise they wouldn't have said "you should probably also specify ..." It's just a matter of design symmetry

Comment: @Prasad Generally no; it doesn't do anything. If you're inheriting someone else's style, though, `paddingRight=0` will override their old style if they have one specified.

Comment: @MatterCat I have reached to the conclusion that this should be `ignored`, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestion. I found a solution that adding `paddingRight=0` solves my problem. Also it doesn't hamper any of my layout, hence treat this as solution.

Answer (score 1):

The hint specifies that "probably" you should keep the same padding on both the sides (left and right), just to keep simmetry. If there are reasons not to do that, you can ignore the hint

Comment: I have suppressed the warning. Thanks